# Attractive force between hose and floor when a pool is filled

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I was filling a rubber pool for my baby using a hose. But I noticed that if I put the hose outlet directly with the floor there is an attractive force!
This is strange, because the hose is throwing water, and by action/reaction it should experiment a repulsive force upward (...I noticed this repulsive force when the hose was a little separated from the floor).
How can this phenomenon be explained?

[image]

Comment: What is the diameter of your hose? What is the wall thickness?

Answer (score 1):

An apparently simple situation can be extremely complex (effects from nozzle on tube, possible helical flow inside tube, ram pump effect, cavitation...), but the most common attractive force in this situation is the **Venturi effect**.
Please check [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect) and [this vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Na9ORhYjvJU).
or if this video is not available from where you are, [via a search engine] (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=venturi+effect&ia=videos)

Answer (score -1):

[image]
I know your nozzle is in the form shown above. Its head has a large area, but its head hole is small.

From the following video, you will know why the hose is sucked at the bottom of the pool. To put it simply, your nozzle section has a relatively large area. It is similar to a disk. When the water flows out, the disc is sucked at the bottom of the pool.

[enter link description here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9aI_zJL1DJ0)